# Camel aborts route processing silently (no exception, no warning or error message in log)

Tags: apache-camel

I have a route with:

```
multicast().to(A, B, C)
```

In cases where I want to skip `B` I defined it as `direct:noop` (via a property in a `.properties` file) with no consumer `noop` defined.

After quite a headache for a few hours I found the following in the [Direct Component's doc](https://camel.apache.org/direct.html):

> `failIfNoConsumers`   Default: true   **Camel 2.16.0:** Indicates whether the producer should fail by throwing an exception when sending to a direct endpoint with no active consumers.

I didn't change the `failIfNoConsumers` option, I'm using Camel 2.22.1, but it doesn't throw an exception but **silently** aborts the processing of the route (including `C` and the default move to `.camel` after completion). Did I get something wrong there?

**Follow-up question:**

If skipping an endpoint doesn't work as tried above, how does it? Do I have to use `choice().when()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `log:noop?level=OFF` to send to an empty op

Comment: Thank you. That looks good. (Though it will take some time to explain my clients why to use this and not the more natural `direct:noop`. :) What about `direct` not throwing an exception contrary to the doc? Can this be considered a bug?

Comment: See the docs with the version you use: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.22.x/camel-core/src/main/docs/direct-component.adoc

Comment: I see, the Camel devs (you?) inverted **failIfNoConsumers**'s default to `false` (and the doc on the website is still not up-to-date). Very tricky. ;)